# Is it more intelligent to use CFMutableArrayRef in this case?

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays

I need to keep track of integer values in an array, and sometimes I need to modify a value in the array.

Right now I do this:

```
// Read an integer from the array
NSNumber* num = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:someInteger];
[numArray addObject:num];
```

To update a value:

```
// Update an integer in the array
NSNumber* num = [numArray lastObject]; // get old
NSInteger numInt = [numInt integerValue]; // convert
NSNumber* newNum = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:numInt + someAddition]; // create new
[numArray removeLastObject]; // remove old
[numArray addObject:newNum]; // set new
```

This is so bad. So many objects involved and all because NSNumber is immutable. Now I thought maybe I must step down into good old C and use CFMutableArrayRef? Can I store simple NSInteger values in there without all this overhead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use replaceObjectAtIndex: withObject: command:

```
[numArray replaceObjectAtIndex:[array count]-1 withObject:newNum];
```

It's better than your method